# Execute Store Procedure For All Rows in SELECT without using Cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have an SQL that returns n rows like,

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
```

For each row, I wanna execute a stored procedure. I know I can use cursor but I wanna avoid cursor? Is it possible?

Comment: You could rewrite your procedure to receive a table valued parameter. But if you can't change the procedure then no you are pretty much stuck looping. You could use your query to generate a dynamic sql string but it will still call your procedure for every row which is likely not going to help much.

Comment: @SeanLange means I have to use a cursor? So should I use fast forward in this case?

Comment: What dose the SP actually do; perhaps you don't even need to use it.

Comment: The SP is very old and complex logic that do some add/update/delete and blah blah.

Comment: The thing is that I have a job that will invoke my sp directly.

Comment: What does "The thing is that I have a job that will invoke my sp directly." mean???

Comment: I have to execute sp with some specfic rows.

Comment: I'm with @SeanLange then. Either recode your SP to accept a table-value parameter, or you'll need to use a `CURSOR`.

Comment: @SeanLange I mean some CI job that calls the sp direclty

Comment: ok which type of cursor fast forward?

Comment: You lost me. At first you said you needed to execute your procedure for each row in a select statement. But not it is called automatically. Which is it?

Comment: This is so vague I am not comfortable offering advice on which fetch options might be appropriate. But it sounds like fast forward might be a reasonable choice along with forward only.

Comment: If you are keeping the stored procedure and it acts on one row at a time, then the cursor is probably the logical method of doing that.  A cursor should not be harmful, the reason for the recommendation against cursors is because it leads to carrying out actions on a row-by-row basis, but in fact you are already doing that.

Comment: @SeanLange sorry for that. I was looking to avoid cursor but as you mention its now not possible. Next I asking which curso type should I use and u answer that as well. Thanks a lot

Comment: Can someone answer that its not possible at least now?

Comment: Myself and at least one or two others have already stated that you can't do this without some kind of looping.

Comment: I mean answer not comment so that I can marked is as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have a couple of choices. Either modify your procedure to receive a table valued function so you can deal with it set based. Or you are stuck doing some sort of looping, most likely a cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to answer because you don't say exactly what you are trying to achieve with the stored procedure, but it's possible that you might be able to use a stored function instead of a stored procedure.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Not sure how using a scalar function is going to address the need to call the procedure for every row in a select statement.

Comment: Well since a storage function can be part of your query by default it is called on every row, again it depends on your business case which wasn't stated in the question.